# How to create instance from Json when one of the constructor params is initialized by default?

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, spray, spray-json

The methods in ADSRegistrationMap are used to save and retrieve the document from MongoDB. ObjectId is created during initialization. I have to do the same to load Registration from Json that is part of POST body, so I thought I could just add ADSRegistrationProtocol object to do that. It fails with compilation error. Any idea on how to fix it or do this better?

```
package model

import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import com.mongodb.DBObject
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.{MongoDBList, MongoDBObject}

case class Registration(
  system: String, 
  identity: String, 
  id: ObjectId = new ObjectId())

object RegistrationProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val registrationFormat = jsonFormat2(Registration)
}

object RegistrationMap {
  def toBson(registration: Registration): DBObject = {
    MongoDBObject(
      "system"         -> registration.system,
      "identity"       -> registration.identity,
      "_id"            -> registration.id
    )
  }

  def fromBson(o: DBObject): Registration = {
    Registration(
      system = o.as[String]("system"),
      identity = o.as[String]("identity"),
      id = o.as[ObjectId]("_id")
    )
  }
}
```

**Compilation Error:**

```
[error] /model/Registration.scala:20: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : model.Registration.type
[error]  required: (?, ?) => ?
[error]  Note: implicit value registrationFormat is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[error]   implicit val registrationFormat = jsonFormat2(Registration)
[error]                                                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

---

Updated ObjectId to String and jsonFormat2 to jsonFormat3 to fix the compilation error.

```
case class Registration(
  system: String, 
  identity: String, 
  id: String = (new ObjectId()).toString())

object RegistrationProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val registrationFormat = jsonFormat3(Registration)
}
```

Getting runtime error now when converting body of POST request to the Registration object. Any idea?

```
val route: Route = {
  pathPrefix("registrations") {
    pathEnd {
      post {
        entity(as[Registration]) { registration =>
```

Here is what is in build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature")

val akkaVersion = "2.3.8"

val sprayVersion = "1.3.1"

resolvers += "spray" at "http://repo.spray.io/"
resolvers += "Sonatype releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"

// Main dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-camel" % akkaVersion,
    "io.spray" % "spray-can" % sprayVersion,
    "io.spray" % "spray-routing" % sprayVersion,
    "io.spray" % "spray-client" % sprayVersion,
    "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % sprayVersion,
    "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1",
    "org.apache.activemq" % "activemq-camel" % "5.8.0",
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2",
    "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.7.4"
)
```

Error:

```
12:33:03.477 [admcore-microservice-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] DEBUG s.can.server.HttpServerConnection - Dispatching POST request to http://localhost:8878/api/v1/adsregistrations to handler Actor[akka://admcore-microservice-system/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/1#-1156351415]
Uncaught error from thread [admcore-microservice-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[admcore-microservice-system]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: spray.json.JsonParser$.apply(Ljava/lang/String;)Lspray/json/JsValue;
    at spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport$$anonfun$sprayJsonUnmarshaller$1.applyOrElse(SprayJsonSupport.scala:36)
    at spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport$$anonfun$sprayJsonUnmarshaller$1.applyOrElse(SprayJsonSupport.scala:34)
```

Comment: I think this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156434/howto-test-custom-json-objects-with-spray-routing since `ObjectId` is not serializable by default. Also, you might need to change `jsonFormat2` to `jsonFormat3`

Comment: Updated ObjectId to String and jsonFormat2 to jsonFormat3 to fix the compilation error. Getting a new runtime error now when converting the body of POST request to Registration instance. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, I think you encountered a compatibility issue with spray-json, see [here](https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/932). Downgrade to `1.2.6` and things should work out. Alternatively you can also copy `SprayJsonSupport` as described in the ticket.

Comment: Downgrading to 1.2.6 worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any issue, I would define the Register class (which seems a data model) as follows

```scala
case class Register(system: String, identity: String, id: String)
```

That's because it makes more sense to me having an `id` field as String rather than as BSON ObjectId (I'm used to datamodel which don't depend on 3rd party libraries).

Therefore, the right SprayJson protocol would make use of `jsonFormat3` rather than `jsonFormat2`:

```scala
object RegistrationProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val registrationFormat = jsonFormat3(Registration)
}
```

And that would solve any kind of JSON serialization issue.

Finally, your `toBson` and `fromBson` converters would be:

```scala
def toBson(r: Registration): DBObject = {
    MongoDBObject(
      "system"    -> r.system,
      "identity"  -> r.identity,
      "_id"       -> new ObjectId(r.id)
    )
  }
```

and

```scala
def fromBson(o: DBObject): Registration = {
    Registration(
      system = o.as[String]("system"),
      identity = o.as[String]("identity"),
      id = o.as[ObjectId]("_id").toString
    )
  }
```

A that's where the BSON ObjectId is being used: much closer to the MongoDB dependant logic.